# How to access and read a file on a USB drive from IOS? (Connected via OTG cable to iPhone)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, usb, ipados

Can I parse a file (access a text file and read contents) on a USB drive from IOS? (Eg OTG cable to iPhone). Is USB device that mounts as file system normally, e.g. on MacBook

Which library/framework to use?

Or is it possible from iPad if not from iPhone?

Clarification: If there is a test.txt file on the USB drive, then ability to open it from iPhone IOS app (assuming connected via OTG cable) read only, then read the contents as a string. Or open for reading as text file and read line by line.

Comment: What does 'parsing a file on a USB drive from iOS' mean?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller?language=objc

Comment: Updates re defining parsing

Comment: UIDocumentPickerViewController - doesn’t mention anything re mounting USB drive?

Comment: Again, what does 'parsing a file on a USB drive from iOS' mean?

Comment: If there is a test.txt file on the USB drive, then ability to open it from iPhone IOS app (assuming connected via OTG cable) read only, then read the contents as a string. On open for reading as text file and read line by line.